# How can I make sure in Prisma that only one item gets updated?

Tags: prisma

I'm nervous that when I perform an update using Prisma that I may accidentally have my *where* clause include an undefined and then all my records in a table will get updated. Is there a good way to mitigate that?

Here is some code that I'm concerned about.

```typescript
const update = await context.prisma.AttendeesCodeCampYearType.update({
        where: {
          Id: dataAttendeesCCYT[0].Id,
        },
        data: {
          EmailSendAll: false,
          EmailOptOutReason: `react app 2 account/emailoptout opt-out ${new Date().toLocaleString()}`,
        },
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update` on a model in Prisma will only ever update a single item, or it will fail if it can't find the item to update. This is because the `where` argument for `update` expects its input to refer to a unique item - that is, some identifier (a single ID, compound ID, or any other unique attribute or attributes) that will only ever refer to one item.

Documentation: *[CRUD, Update a single record](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/crud#update-a-single-record)*

`updateMany` in comparison will update 0 or more documents, which might be nothing, might be one item, and might be more than one.

Comment: Thanks @Shea. I'm so use to being burned by SQL UPDATE, I forget to check to see if PRISMA fixed that. Be better if there were a SQL UPDATEMANY.